# Why does Excel saves csv with "," instead of ";" (using Powershell)

Tags: excel, powershell, vba

I'm using PowerShell to save Excel as Csv through Ole Automation :

```
$Sheet.SaveAs($FileName + ".csv", 6)
```

Why does Excel saves csv with "," with Ole Automation and with ";" when doing by hand ?

Regional Settings delimiter is ";"

Update : finally on other forums it seems this is a real hard question with no real solution as it seems like a bug.

Answer (score 1):

When you save a CSV from Excel you have these options (with Regional Settings delimiter -> ";")

```vbs
Option Explicit

Public Sub SaveCSV()
    With ActiveWorkbook

        .SaveAs Filename:="C:\x.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV         ' 6: -> ","
        .SaveAs Filename:="C:\x.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSVMSDOS    '24: -> ","

        .SaveAs Filename:="C:\x.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSVWindows  '23: -> ";"
        .SaveAs Filename:="C:\x.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSVMac      '22: -> ";"

    End With
End Sub
```

In your PowerShell script you're using **6** (FileFormat)

---

.

There is another factor that can change the delimiter in Excel - TextToColumns:

```vbs
Public Sub testDelim()
    setDelim "@"
End Sub

Public Sub setDelim(ByVal delim As String)
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    If 1 Then   '-------------------------------------------------- Change delimiter
        Range("A1") = "A" & delim & "1"
        Range("A1").TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), _
                                  DataType:=xlDelimited, _
                                  TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
                                  ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
                                  Tab:=False, _
                                  Semicolon:=False, _
                                  Comma:=False, _
                                  Space:=False, _
                                  Other:=True, _
                                  OtherChar:=delim
        Range("A1:B1") = vbNullString
    Else    '------------------------------------------------------ Reset delimiter
        Range("A1") = "x"
        Range("A1").TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), _
                                  DataType:=xlDelimited, _
                                  TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
                                  ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
                                  Tab:=False, _
                                  Semicolon:=False, _
                                  Comma:=False, _
                                  Space:=False, _
                                  Other:=False, _
                                  OtherChar:=""
        Range("A1") = vbNullString
    End If
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: when I do by hand, I chose CSV neither dos, mac,... so there is discrepancy between VBA (,) and Manual Behavior (;) ?

Comment: weirdly even with 23 I get "," instead of ";" (I'm on Windows 10)

Comment: I'm not sure how Win10 differs